# MySQL - Query to update all rows with foreign reference values?

Tags: mysql, sql

Initially I have three tables with links;

TableC -> TableB-> TableA

```
CREATE TABLE TableA (
    id int(15) PRIMARY KEY, 
    name char(25) not null
);

CREATE TABLE TableB (
    id int(15), 
    A_id int(15) not null, 
    Foreign Key(A_id) references TableA(id),
);

CREATE TABLE TableC (
    id int(15), 
    B_id int(15) not null, 
    Foreign Key(B_id) references TableB(id),
);
```

I want to drop the TableB after adding TableA's foreign key directly on TableC like;

TableC -> TableA

If I have hundreads of TableC rows, how to migrate those existing data?
I tried below query but failed with cause more than 1 rows. .

`update TableC set A_id = ( select ta.id from TableC tc, TableB tb, TableA ta where tc.B_id=tb.id and tb.A_id=ta.id );`

Could you please help?

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  What if you have multiple values for a given `A` record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use a straight forward subquery.

```
UPDATE tablec
       SET a_id = (SELECT b.a_id
                          FROM tableb b
                          WHERE b.id = tablec.b_id);
```